# How to solve sequential split dynamically

Tags: algorithm

There is a number of weight in array arr.
arr= [1,5,3,2,4],  each of the value in arr contains weight.
n = 2, must have 2 blocks while split the weight and order cannot break for split

```
Combination 1: 
block 0: [1]        max: 1
block 1: [5,3,2,4]  max: 5
----------------------------
sum of max from block 0 and 1 is 6

Combination 2: 
block 0: [1,5]      max: 5
block 1: [3,2,4]    max: 4
----------------------------
sum of max from block 0 and 1 is 9

Combination 3: 
block 0: [1,5,3]    max: 5
block 1: [2,4]      max: 4
----------------------------
sum of max from block 0 and 1 is 9

Combination 4: 
block 0: [1,5,3, 2] max: 5
block 1: [4]        max: 4
----------------------------
sum of max from block 0 and 1 is 9

So here answer is 6 from Combination 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The hardest part of some problems is just stating them clearly. If you can do that, the code practically writes itself.

I think the problem statement is this: Find the minimum value of a function (f) applied at every index of an array (f(array, index)), where f is the sum of the max values of two subarrays formed by splitting the input array at the given index.

```js
function f(array, index) {
  let left = array.slice(0, index)
  let right = array.slice(index)
  return Math.max(...left) + Math.max(...right)
}

let array = [1, 5, 3, 2, 4]
let smallestMax = Infinity
for (let i=1; i<array.length; i++) {
  let max = f(array, i)
  smallestMax = max < smallestMax ? max : smallestMax
}
console.log(smallestMax)
```

Comment: Well done, very clean though there is a linear time solution, but it's a little bit more messy.

Answer (score 0):

@Danh has a straightforward O(N^2) solution, but linear time is also possible without too much more work, and if you have enough data, it'll make a huge difference. Dan did his in JS it looks like, so I'll try to do the same. A bit rusty on these style for loops, so they may be off by one, but quick test in the JS console gave me 6 as expected (after fixing a copy/paste error).

Idea is to pass left to right finding the max at each index (left side). Then right to left finding the max at each index (right side). Then we look at left side plus the right side to get the value. Basically dynamic programming of a sort.

```
let array = [1, 5, 3, 2, 4]
let maxLeft = {}
let maxRight = {}
let max,newMax;

for (let i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
  if (i === 0) {
    maxLeft[i] = array[i]
  } else {
    maxLeft[i] = array[i] < maxLeft[i-1] ? maxLeft[i-1] : array[i]
  }
}

for (let i=array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (i === array.length - 1) {
    maxRight[i] = array[i]
  } else {
    maxRight[i] = array[i] < maxRight[i+1] ? maxRight[i+1] : array[i]
  }
}

for (let i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
  newMax = maxLeft[i] + maxRight[i + 1]
  if (i === 0) {
    max = newMax 
  } else {
    maxLeft[i] = newMax < maxLeft[i-1] ? max : newMax 
  }
}
console.log(max)
```